# 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied [LARAVEL]

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm doing some records to the database and from time to time came out this error:

```
local.ERROR: exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]
[1045] Access denied for user 'homestead'@'localhost'
(using password: YES)' in
:\WEB\litraen\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:55
```

I have the file env. properly configured.

env.

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=auth
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=
```

Comment: would you include `config/database.php` content ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check in `config/database.php` if

```
'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
```

And in connections Array

```
 'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'tracker'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', 'root'),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => false,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```